# Visual Studio can't find Qt includes

Tags: qt, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I am using the Qt framework for a personal project of mine. I have installed Qt 5.12.9 and have the msvc2017 toolset with my vs2019. I put the correct path to the include directory of the qt install which would be 'E:\Qt\5.12.9\msvc2017\include'(My Qt install is on my second drive). I also put the correct path to the corresponding lib folder and added the specific .lib files i would be using to 'Additional Dependencies' line in the linker input options. I have the vs2017 toolset selected and the Qt 5.12.9 msvc2017 bin is in my path. No matter what I do Visual Studio can't seem to find any Qt includes whatsoever?? Does anyone have any advice on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have selected MSVC 2017 in Qt, then you will need to download & install **Visual Studio Community Edition 2017** and select at least the following packages:

1. MSBuild
2. Static analysis tools
3. Visual studio 2017 redistributable
4. Windows 10 SDK

For Qt 5.15.0 and VS2019, here is the answer for the same
[How to solve "No suitable kits found" in Qt Creator 4.12.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62620287/how-to-solve-no-suitable-kits-found-in-qt-creator-4-12-3/62621303#62621303)

Adding Screenshots of Qt Maintenance Tool and VS2017

[image]
[image]

Comment: VS2019 will not work. You have to download VS2017 as Qt 5.12 doesn't support VS2019

Comment: ***Qt 5.12 doesn't support VS2019*** I use Qt-5.9 every day with Visual Studio 2019. With that said I don't use the addon.

Comment: @Chilarai, So even after installing the 'MSVC v141 - VS 2017 C++ x64/x86 build tools' for VS 2019 with the VS 2019 installer, It won't work?

Comment: @drescherjm, how does 5.9 work with Visual Studio 2019 but not 5.12? Would you suggest just using 5.9 instead? On the Qt website under the supported platforms for Qt 5.9, it says it only supports VS 2013 - 2017 just like the page for 5.12 does. I assume you are using the 2017 tool set like I was trying to? But if that is working for you, I'm not sure what's wrong

Comment: @myopunk, that I did not check before